# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DataList' in type cast flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================

> The following _CastError was thrown building ItemTags(dirty, dependencies: [DataListInherited], state: _ItemTagsState#a7193):
> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DataList' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was:

> ItemTags ItemTags:file:///C:/Users/hp/AndroidStudioProjects/edufly/lib/pages/edit_product/components/edit_product_form.dart:172:22

Comment: Can you provide source code  that generate this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to assign a `null` to a variable or parameter that expects `DataList`. Since in such cases `DataList` or one of its subclass is mandatory, anything else will trigger a similar error. Since `null` (the unknown) is not a subclass of `DataList`, you get this error.

In order to solve this problem, you will need to find line **172** of **:///C:/Users/hp/AndroidStudioProjects/edufly/lib/pages/edit_product/components/edit_product_form.dart** and carefully review the possible reasons of this anomaly. Once you have understood why a `null` is being passed, you will be able to either logically fix the error, or handle the edge-case accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `null` objects in your `DataList`.

Answer (score 0):

**I got this when I was using the `flutter_tags` plug in (the null-safe v1 version).**

I fixed it by replacing `Tags` and `ItemTags` with the Flutter built in `ActionChip` widget.

Other benefits besides it working and being built in is that the API is much simpler too.
I wrapped my `ActionChip`'s in a `Wrap` widget.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i upgraded Flutter to 3.10.6 with the package "flutter_tags". I have changed only the `ItemTags` into [`ActionChip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ActionChip-class.html) as mentioned above by @Turkey.